# Could NSTask call a bash shell that having a read command in it and waiting for an input value?

Tags: swift, macos, shell, process, nstask

I'm developing a macOS App which should use `Process` to run a shell script. The function somehow like this:

```
func shellDemo(launchPath: String?, args: [String]?, onComplete: RunShellScriptResult? = nil, onFail: RunShellScriptResult? = nil) -> Void {
        
        let task = Process()
        task.launchPath = launchPath
        task.arguments = args
        task.launch()
        
        task.terminationHandler = { myTask in
            if !myTask.isRunning {
                let status = myTask.terminationStatus
                if status == 0 {
                    onComplete?("success")
                } else {
                    onFail?("error")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and I create a simple `ShellTest.sh` file in the Application bundle, then call the `shellDemo()` function like this:

```
let path = "/bin/bash"
guard let filePath = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "ShellTest", withExtension: "sh")?.path else {
    return
}
let args = ["\(filePath)"]
shellDemo(launchPath: path, args: args) { (success) in
    print(success)
} onFail: { (fail) in
    print(fail)
}
```

So far so good, until I use `read` to wait for an input value in my script. For example, the script `ShellTest.sh` could be :

```
echo -n "input your name pls:"
read  name
echo "hello $name "
```

The questoin is I can only input the value in my debug console, how could I pass the input value in my code?

Comment: What programming language is this? For sure it is not posix shell.

Comment: This's MacOS App using Swift language